# OpenGL crashes when linking program, LG Nexus 4

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, fragment-shader

I'm having another OpenGL ES driver error. This time I'm trying to compile the following lines:

```
precision mediump float; 
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate; 


void main() { 
 highp vec4 color = texture2D(input0, textureCoordinate); 


vec3 color3 = color.rgb;

vec2 tc = (2.0 * textureCoordinate) - 1.0;
float d = dot(tc, tc);
vec2 lookup = vec2(d, color3.r);

..   
..
}
```

but I'm getting after the line:

```
GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
```

native crash : "Fatal signal 11(SIGDEV) at 0x00000060(code = 1), thread 1231 "
I'm guessing that it happens because LG nexus 4 uses GPU Adreno, and it also crashes for me with error code 14 on a different crash - using too many macros.

Comment: If we are looking for bugs in your shader code, you should include _complete_ shader code. That's missing all variable declarations, and I'm assuming you left some stuff out at the end. Also some application code could be helpful.

Comment: Possibly your shader code is not compiling, and thus your program fails to link. By the way, OpenGL ES does not have shaders, so it is irrelevant to add OpenGL ES tag here.

Comment: Please provide full shader code.

Comment: do you have operator `for` in your vertex shader?

Comment: no I don't have any for nor if, what I did is to investigate about the  Adreno capabilities. The results are that it has some serious errors when it compile GLSL code into GPU instructions code. Unfortunately we just disabled some of our filters to devices that use Adreno GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you compile the shader, using `glGetShaderiv` get the status of the shader compilation. Like:

```
GLint compiled;
glGetShaderiv(index, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);  //index is the shader value
```

Then, if compiled is returned as zero, get the info length first, and then the error message as follows:

```
GLint infoLen = 0;
glGetShaderiv(index, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

if(infoLen > 1)
{
    char* infoLog = new char(infoLen);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(index, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
}
```

Check `infoLog` finally to see the error message that returned from shader compilation. Segmentation fault message in your original post does not give anything useful to solve the problem.

Comment: I can't get to this check since I'm getting this native crash while linking the program. I did use the info for some other linking problems that wasn't native though

Comment: You should be compiling your shaders before linking the program so you should be able to get the info. You can just print the info on Android log.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your short code excerpt in your fragment shader you haven't specified `float` precision. In ES 2.0 you must explicitly specify `float` precision.

```
precision mediump float;
```

Please read about this [in specs](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf), p. *4.5.3 Default Precision Qualifiers*.
Shader may work without specifying `float` precision on certain OpenGL ES drivers and may fail to compile on another ones.

However, full source code is needed to find out exact cause of your issue.

I'd suggest you to start commenting out parts of shader code until it starts compiling correctly. This way you will narrow down a problematic line (I believe even faster than waiting for answer here on SO).

Comment: hi, I added the precision lines above. it wasn't the problem

Comment: Keep calm and comment out line by line until you find the cause.